# Beignet fails on a machine with Intel GPU and an NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: arch-linux, intel, gpu

I'm on Arch Linux, and I'd like to make use of [Beignet](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/). However, for unrelated reasons, my graphics are provided by an NVIDIA graphics card (using the nouveau driver), which causes any attempt to use Beignet to fail automatically. I know that the onboard Intel GPU can work, but for some reason, I can't make use of it.

This is what I get when I run `clinfo`:

```
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.4 (git-7f1c190c)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_intel_media_block_io cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

When I try `luxmark`, I get this instead:

```
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetDeviceIDs
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My assumption that the Intel GPU is available for my use comes from this line being in my `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Am I missing something obvious here? My exact hardware, according to `lspci` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is as follows:

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)`

`vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x12
cpu MHz         : 1236.840
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs            :
bogomips        : 7187.42
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:`

Comment: Could you provide more info about your hardware?

Comment: @mattia.b89 What do you need to know? There's a lot of 'info about my hardware' I could provide.

Comment: Is it a Mac? How the two graphic cards are handled?

Comment: @mattia.b89 I specified that I'm on Arch Linux, and the cards are handled by the nouveau driver (for the NVIDIA card) and the Intel open-source driver (for the onboard), although the latter is currently unused.

Comment: I asked you for HARDWARE information, not SOFTWARE

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Beignet by default uses X11/DRI to find the GPU. This won't work with a discrete card as the primary display.

You can unset the DISPLAY environment variable or set it to "" to run a non-X OpenCL application, as Beignet will use render nodes to find the Intel GPU instead.

You need to recompile Beignet without X11 support to have X apps like Luxmark working.

I filed a bug asking Beignet to use render nodes by default:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107582

HTH,